# Make /usr/local/lib a default library search path for ld on mac os x?

Tags: c++, xcode, path, linker-errors, ld

I have XCode installed, but for some reason, /usr/local/lib is not amongst the default library search paths:

```
gcc -Xlinker -v
```

gives me:

```
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-224.1
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 armv6m armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

This is unfortunate since `/usr/local/lib` is a fairly canonical location for installed libraries and and there is no `/etc/ld.so.conf`+`ldconfig` on `mac os x` to modify the default library search paths. So without using `-L/usr/local/lib` this results in a linker error. Is there any other, non-runtime option than setting the environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

**EDIT**: Setting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable did nothing for me. I had to set the `LIBRARY_PATH` env variable instead to be able to link libraries installed under `/usr/local/lib` with `gcc`.

Was there an option about this when installing `XCode`? (it's a work computer, haven't installed it myself)

Comment: No option that I saw when I installed Xcode. Also, neither `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` nor `LIBRARY_PATH` nor `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889799/libraries-in-usr-local-lib-not-found) worked for me. Still searching for a solution.

Comment: What does `gcc -Xlinker -v` give you? I added this to my `~/.bash_profile`: `if [ -z "${LIBRARY_PATH}" ] #\n
then #\n
        export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib" #\n
else #\n
        export LIBRARY_PATH="LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib" #\n
fi`  (showing newlines with `#\n`). After this, `gcc -Xlinker -v` also lists `/usr/local/lib` (open a new terminal window for `.bash_profile` to take effect)

Comment: `gcc -Xlinker -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-241.9
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
 /usr/lib
 /usr/local/lib
Framework search paths:
 /Library/Frameworks/
 /System/Library/Frameworks/
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Also, man ld states:
`Search paths
     ld maintains a list of directories to search for a library or framework
     to use.  The default library search path is /usr/lib then /usr/local/lib.
       The -F option will add a new framework
     search path.  The -Z option will remove the standard search paths.  The
     -syslibroot option will prepend a prefix to all search paths.`

Comment: are your environment variables correctly set up? try `echo $LIBRARY_PATH` in a terminal. I know, the `man` page of `ld` does say this, but it's not correct

Comment: sorry missed that the library search path was listed correctly. For me that is all that was needed to make the linker have the right paths when compiling.

Comment: No $LIBRARY_PATH variable is set up on mine. However, xcode does state that it searches /usr/local/lib and so does ld. So that is strange that you had to set yours up like that.

Comment: Anyways, I set up my bash_profile to export that $LIBRARY_PATH just in case...

Answer (score 5):

To add a temporary library to my project using Xcode I did the following:

[image]

To add a temporary include path to my XCode library search paths I had to do the following:

[image]

If you want to add default [include and search paths](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) you need to use:

For include paths:

```
CPATH
C_INCLUDE_PATH
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
```

And for library paths:

```
LIBRARY_PATH
```

In order for Xcode and other GUI applications in OS X (tested on 10.10) to be able to access these environment variables, you need to set variables using:

```
/bin/launchctl setenv LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib
/bin/launchctl setenv CPATH /usr/local/include
```

But these are not permanent. In order to have these variables across restarts, you need to create a startup script. [See this page for an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite/25912736#25912736)

Comment: Your `gcc -Xlinker -v` does list the right library search path, did you do this in XCode before listing the result of `gcc -Xlinker -v`? Or I suspect your environment variables are correctly set. For me that was all what was needed.

Comment: Does it now work for projects that do not use XCode i.e. is it a global setting, or restricted to the project? (and do you still have your env variables LIBRARY_PATH set up?)

Comment: very useful for me regarding the default include and search paths! just put it in my .zshrc file

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables starting with DYLD_ like DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH are specific to Apple's dynamic link editor called dyld. The manual pages state:

> **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH**
> This is a colon separated list of directories  that  contain  libraries.  The  dynamic  linker
> searches  these  directories before it searches the default locations for libraries. It allows
> you to test new versions of existing libraries.
> For each library that a program uses, the dynamic linker looks for it  in  each  directory  in
> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH  in  turn.  If  it still can't find the library, it then searches DYLD_FALL-
> BACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH and DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH in turn. Use the -L option to otool(1).  to discover the frameworks and shared libraries that the  exe-
> cutable is linked against.

Please note that the DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH already contains a reference to standard /usr/local/lib by default.

> **DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH**
> This  is  a  colon  separated  list  of directories that contain libraries.  It is used as the
> default location for libraries not found in their install path.  By  default,  it  is  set  to
> $(HOME)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib.

Xcode has Project-wide or Target-specific Build Settings such as "Library Search Paths" where you would define paths to non-standard locations that you need to let the linker know about.

Apart from copying and adding *.dylib files to your Xcode project you need to "make install" those to one of these known library locations. Otherwise the O/S loader (launchd process) cannot use them during actual launch or run-time of your app image.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/UsingDynamicLibraries.html

Please note that C++ as well as Object-C have their challenges regarding Dynamic Libraries.