# Kannel Sqlbox not working (trying to connect to SQL Server instead of MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sms-gateway, smpp, kannel

I have a `Kannel` up and running on an Ubuntu 16.04 box, with local MySQL DLR storage. I want to add `sqlbox` to queue the incoming SMS in the same database.

When I try to launch the `sqlbox sqlbox.conf`, here is what I get.

```
  2017-08-03 14:02:21 [55982] [0] INFO: Starting to log to file /var/log/kannel/kannel-sqlbox.log level 0
  2017-08-03 14:02:21 [55982] [0] INFO: Added logfile `/var/log/kannel/kannel-sqlbox.log' with level `0'.
  2017-08-03 14:02:21 [55982] [0] PANIC: SQLBOX: MSSql: connection settings for id 'sqlbox-db' are not specified!
  2017-08-03 14:02:21 [55982] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(gw_backtrace+0xce) [0x42d07e]
  2017-08-03 14:02:21 [55982] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(gw_panic+0x16f) [0x42d1ff]
  2017-08-03 14:02:21 [55982] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(sqlbox_init_mssql+0x11e) [0x40dffe]
  2017-08-03 14:02:21 [55982] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(sqlbox_init_sql+0x9) [0x413239]
  2017-08-03 14:02:21 [55982] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(main+0x31d) [0x40c24d]
  2017-08-03 14:02:21 [55982] [0] PANIC: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7fbb36421830]
  2017-08-03 14:02:21 [55982] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(_start+0x29) [0x40c4d9]
```

Here are the two config files `sqlbox.conf`:

```
group = sqlbox
id = sqlbox-db
smsbox-id = sqlbox-db
global-sender = "My Sender"
bearerbox-host = "192.168.1.2"
bearerbox-port = 14001
smsbox-port = 14005
#smsbox-port-ssl = false
sql-log-table = sent_sms
sql-insert-table = send_sms
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/kannel-sqlbox.log"
log-level = 0

group = mysql-connection
id = sqlbox-db
host = localhost
username = "user"
password = "pwd"
database = "kannel"
```

and `kannel.conf`

```
group = core
admin-port = 14000
admin-password = pwd
status-password = pwd
# admin-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
admin-allow-ip = 192.168.1.2
access-log = "/var/log/kannel/access/log"
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/kannel.log"
box-allow-ip = 192.168.1.2
log-level = 0
smsbox-port= 14001
dlr-storage = mysql

# SMSBOX SETUP

group = smsbox
smsbox-id = sqlbox-id
bearerbox-host = 192.168.1.2
sendsms-port = 14002
global-sender = My Sender
sendsms-chars = "0123456789 +-"
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsbox.log"

# SENDING SMS

group = sendsms-user
username = test
password = test
concatenation = true
max-messages = 1

# SMSC 
#The sms part

# SQL BOX CONFIG

group = mysql-connection
id = sqlbox-db
host = localhost
username = user
password = pwd
database = kannel

# DLR SETUP

group = mysql-connection
id = mydlr
host = localhost
username = user
password = pwd
database = kannel
group = dlr-db
id = mydlr
table = dlr
field-smsc=smsc
field-timestamp=ts
field-destination=destination
field-source=source
field-service=service
field-url=url
field-mask=mask
field-status=status
field-boxc-id=boxc
```

What is the trick ? Thank you

Using:
`kannel 1.4.4-2build1` and `kannel-sqlbox 0.7.2-4build1` both installed via `apt`.

Comment: Can you add more details about the version of kannel and sqlbox that you are using (version number, origin: installed with apt-get, or recompiled on your side?)

Comment: please see my edit @NicolasR

Comment: I think `kannel 0.7.2-4build1` is `kannel-sqlbox 0.7.2-4build1`, right?

Comment: Yes @NicolasR exactly. I fixed it.

Comment: Good, I posted my looooong answer. As you can see, I spent some time to fix it this year!

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. Do you think the version is stable enough? Any problems with it? I'm wondering whether the fact kannel is not very actively maintained is an issue or not.

Comment: No problem si far with 1.5.0, less problems than 1.4.4!

Comment: Keep me updated once you tried

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

The main problem as depicted in the log is there:

`2017-08-03 14:02:21 [55982] [0] PANIC: SQLBOX: MSSql: connection settings for id 'sqlbox-db' are not specified!`

In fact, there is a problem in the version that you are using (**apt-get packages are old versions that you can't use there**), I got the same problem at the beginning of the year.

Here is how I made it work.

---

## Solution

### Step 1 - Uninstall all your previous Kannel packages, clean everything

If you already installed Kannel with apt-get packages, you have to clean your machine first.

Here are some clues to find the items that you have to remove.
I first checked every place where "kannel" was found:

```
sudo find / -name "*kannel*"
sudo find / -name "*Kannel*"
```

Then I ran the following commands (some of them may not be useful for you, depending on your settings, etc):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge kannel
sudo rm -rf /etc/kannel/
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge kannel-sqlbox
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/kannel-sqlbox_0.7.2-4build1_amd64.deb
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/kannel-extras_1.4.4-2build1_amd64.deb
rm /home/nico/www-dev/kannelStore/kannel.store*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/kannel
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/kannel
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/kannel
rm /var/tmp/kannel.swp
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man8/kannel.8
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man8/run_kannel_box.8
```

And also `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/sbin/` (but be careful here, depending on what you already have in the folder!)

---

### Step 2 - Install latest Kannel version from the source

Note: you will have to use version 1.5.0

#### Get dependencies

First add all the packages that you need for the future commands:

- `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` (needed for step `./configure`, or you will get "configure: error: You MUST have the libxml2 (aka gnome-xml) library installed")
- `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` (needed for `./configure --with-mysql`)
- `sudo apt-get install bison` (needed for `make`)
- `sudo apt-get install libssh-dev libssl-dev` (needed for `make` to avoid getting this error: "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [test/test_http] Error 1 ")

#### Get Kannel sources

You will have to get the sources from a svn repository. So:

- `sudo apt install subversion` if you don't have subversion yet (you can check by running `svn --version`: if no reply, use the command)

Then:

- Go to the folder that will host the sources locally. For example on m side: `cd ~/www-dev/nicopushkannel/Kannel/Kannel-Source`
- Get Kannel sources from the repository: `svn co https://svn.kannel.org/gateway/trunk`

#### Build and install Kannel

From the previous step you should be on Kannel sources root foolder.
As described in Kannel documentation, run:

```
cd trunk
./bootstrap
./configure --with-mysql --with-mysql-dir=/var/lib/mysql
make
```

Here the important things are the parameters added to ./configure: `--with-mysql --with-mysql-dir=/var/lib/mysql`

Then install:

```
sudo make bindir=/usr/local/kannel install
```

#### Run Kannel

Once this has been done, you can try to run Kannel from command line:

```
cd /usr/local/sbin
./bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf
```

---

### Step 3 - Install latest Kannel-sqlbox version from the source

Note: You need to have Kannel installed (step 2) to compile sqlbox.

sqlbox is included in Kannel trunk: navigate to the folder:

```
cd addons/sqlbox
```

#### Patch bootstrap file

You may have to patch the bootstrap file to match your autoconf version (was 1.15 for me), as the code don't understand that 1.15 is > than 1.11...

Change the following value to match your machine version of autoconf:

```
if automake-1.11 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  amvers="-1.11"
```

So for me it became:

```
if automake-1.15 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  amvers="-1.15"
```

#### Build and install sqlbox

```
./bootstrap
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

We are done!

One more thing: if you want to add Sqlbox startup at Kannel startup:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/kannel
Add "START_SQLBOX=1" line at the end
```

Comment: For anyone having issue with automake version :
From https://www.kannel.org/pipermail/users/2016-May/022864.html, 
To install sqlbox, you don’t need the bootstrap script.
Just type ./configure and then make.

Comment: Compiled and installed OK, but libgwlib.so was placed in /usr/local/lib and it was not found by the executable on ubuntu 20.04. Solved with https://stackoverflow.com/a/17892806/6449978