# sqlbox looking for mysql instead of mssql

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, kannel

I tried to start the sqlbox but it panicked, I ran:

```
sqlbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/sqlbox.conf
```

Below is the log:

```
2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] INFO: Debug_lvl = 0, log_file = <none>, log_lvl = 0
2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] DEBUG: Kannel sqlbox version `1.4.4'.
Build `Apr  5 2016 13:32:05', compiler `5.3.1 20160330'.
System Linux, release 4.4.0-93-generic, version #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017, machine x86_64.
Hostname smpp.bothsmsw.com, IP 127.0.0.1.
Libxml version 2.9.3.
Using OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016.
Compiled with MySQL 5.7.11, using MySQL 5.7.19.
Compiled with PostgreSQL 9.5.2.
Using SQLite 3.11.0.
Using hiredis API 0.13.3
Using native malloc.

2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] INFO: Starting to log to file /var/log/kannel/sqlbox.log level 0
2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] INFO: Added logfile `/var/log/kannel/sqlbox.log' with level `0'.
2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] PANIC: SQLBOX: MSSql: connection settings for id 'sqlbox-db' are not specified!
2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(gw_backtrace+0xce) [0x42d07e]
2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(gw_panic+0x16f) [0x42d1ff]
2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(sqlbox_init_mssql+0x11e) [0x40dffe]
2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(sqlbox_init_sql+0x9) [0x413239]
2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(main+0x31d) [0x40c24d]
2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] PANIC: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f3146101830]
2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] PANIC: sqlbox(_start+0x29) [0x40c4d9]
```

I don't why appearing as Compiled with PostgreSQL 9.5.2., I don't use it before, how I can recompile with mysql only & here is the sqlbox configuration:

```
#SQLBOX
group = sqlbox
id = sqlbox-db
smsbox-id = sqlbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
bearerbox-port = 18001
smsbox-port = 18005
smsbox-port-ssl = false
sql-log-table = sent_sms
sql-insert-table = send_sms
log-level = 0
log-file = /var/log/kannel/sqlbox.log

# SQLBOX SETUP
group = mysql-connection
id = sqlbox-db
host = localhost
port = 3306
username = root
password = pass
database = kannel_db
max-connections = 25
```

any idea please?

Comment: Hello, I'm experiencing the same problem as yours and as this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/45486238/4885217 . Did you handle it?

Comment: I'm still having the same issue with no reponse !!

Comment: Did you recompile kannel and sqlbox or directly used the precompiled packages? I had the same problem a few months ago

Answer (score 1):

As replied in this topic [Kannel Sqlbox not working (trying to connect to SQL Server instead of MySQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486238/kannel-sqlbox-not-working-trying-to-connect-to-sql-server-instead-of-mysql) you can't use the apt-get packages as they are not built with the right parameters.

## Problem

The main problem as depicted in the log is there:

`2017-08-31 13:27:56 [18635] [0] PANIC: SQLBOX: MSSql: connection settings for id 'sqlbox-db' are not specified!`

In fact, there is a problem in the version that you are using (**apt-get packages are old versions that you can't use there**), I got the same problem at the beginning of the year.

Here is how I made it work.

---

## Solution

### Step 1 - Uninstall all your previous Kannel packages, clean everything

If you already installed Kannel with apt-get packages, you have to clean your machine first.

Here are some clues to find the items that you have to remove.
I first checked every place where "kannel" was found:

```
sudo find / -name "*kannel*"
sudo find / -name "*Kannel*"
```

Then I ran the following commands (some of them may not be useful for you, depending on your settings, etc):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge kannel
sudo rm -rf /etc/kannel/
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge kannel-sqlbox
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/kannel-sqlbox_0.7.2-4build1_amd64.deb
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/kannel-extras_1.4.4-2build1_amd64.deb
rm /home/nico/www-dev/kannelStore/kannel.store*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/kannel
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/kannel
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/kannel
rm /var/tmp/kannel.swp
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man8/kannel.8
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man8/run_kannel_box.8
```

And also `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/sbin/` (but be careful here, depending on what you already have in the folder!)

---

### Step 2 - Install latest Kannel version from the source

Note: you will have to use version 1.5.0

#### Get dependencies

First add all the packages that you need for the future commands:

- `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` (needed for step `./configure`, or you will get "configure: error: You MUST have the libxml2 (aka gnome-xml) library installed")
- `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` (needed for `./configure --with-mysql`)
- `sudo apt-get install bison` (needed for `make`)
- `sudo apt-get install libssh-dev libssl-dev` (needed for `make` to avoid getting this error: "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [test/test_http] Error 1 ")

#### Get Kannel sources

You will have to get the sources from a svn repository. So:

- `sudo apt install subversion` if you don't have subversion yet (you can check by running `svn --version`: if no reply, use the command)

Then:

- Go to the folder that will host the sources locally. For example on m side: `cd ~/www-dev/nicopushkannel/Kannel/Kannel-Source`
- Get Kannel sources from the repository: `svn co https://svn.kannel.org/gateway/trunk`

#### Build and install Kannel

From the previous step you should be on Kannel sources root foolder.
As described in Kannel documentation, run:

```
cd trunk
./bootstrap
./configure --with-mysql --with-mysql-dir=/var/lib/mysql
make
```

Here the important things are the parameters added to ./configure: `--with-mysql --with-mysql-dir=/var/lib/mysql`

Then install:

```
sudo make bindir=/usr/local/kannel install
```

#### Run Kannel

Once this has been done, you can try to run Kannel from command line:

```
cd /usr/local/sbin
./bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf
```

---

### Step 3 - Install latest Kannel-sqlbox version from the source

Note: You need to have Kannel installed (step 2) to compile sqlbox.

sqlbox is included in Kannel trunk: navigate to the folder:

```
cd addons/sqlbox
```

#### Patch bootstrap file

You may have to patch the bootstrap file to match your autoconf version (was 1.15 for me), as the code don't understand that 1.15 is > than 1.11...

Change the following value to match your machine version of autoconf:
    if automake-1.11 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      amvers="-1.11"

So for me it became:
    if automake-1.15 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      amvers="-1.15"

#### Build and install sqlbox

```
./bootstrap
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

We are done!

One more thing: if you want to add Sqlbox startup at Kannel startup:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/kannel
Add "START_SQLBOX=1" line at the end
```

Comment: I've following the above points, step by step to install kannel and sql-box. When I reached the last point which is 

cd /usr/local/sbin
./bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf

I got the following

root@smpp:/usr/local/sbin# ./bearerbox -v 0 /etc/kannel/kannel.conf
./bearerbox: error while loading shared libraries: libgwlib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
root@smpp:/usr/local/sbin#

any idea please?