# g++ link or reference not working with a locally installed library: undefined reference

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, linker, g++, quickfix

I'm trying to compile a quickfix program on Ubuntu but I get undefined references to `FIX::`, as if the `-lquickfix` option were not placed in the g++ command. Actually, I get the same result without this link option.

First I've downloaded, compiled, and run the test of quickfix. Everything worked fine. I did the `sudo make install` and checked the library was cached after runing `sudo ldconfig`:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep quickfix
libquickfix.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libquickfix.so.16
libquickfix.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libquickfix.so
```

This is the g++ command I used:

```
$ g++ -fexceptions -finline-functions -lquickfix -lpthread -lxml2 -std=c++11 Application.cpp tradeclient.cpp -o tradeclient
```

BTW, I've run the same quickfix intallation steps on Debian and the compile command worked fine.

I've read posts like [Libraries in /usr/local/lib not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889799/libraries-in-usr-local-lib-not-found), used the `-L` option for link directories, and `-I` for include paths but I'm still not finding a solution.

Comment: [Your linkage consumes libraries before the object files that refer to them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43305704/1362568)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I've realized that indeed there was a problem in the order of arguments of g++ command. Placing `Application.cpp` and `tradeclient.cpp` at the end causes the undefined references; if I place them at first, before -l options, it works. What confused me was that this command worked fine in Debian regardless where I place these two files. I'm not sure yet why that happens.

Comment: Hi. Pre-Debian 7, linkage was old-school (as RedHat & friends still are). Dependency
order was enforced for static libraries not shared libraries (which were all
linked whether needed or not). Debian 7 went over to dependency order for all
libraries and Debian-based distros (Ubuntu etc.) followed suit. Maybe your
Debian host is pre-7?

Comment: Hi Mike, in my case, I tried on Debian 7, 8, and 9, always with the same results: order seems not to matter. On the other hand, on Ubuntu 16 and 17 the order does matter.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll check it out too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This example shows that the linking argument order using  g++ may or may not matter depending on the OS you’re using.

main.cpp:

```
extern int x_global;
int y_func(int a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int x = x_global + 1;
  return y_func(x);
}
```

x.cpp:

```
int x_global = 2;
```

y.cpp:

```
int y_func(int a) {
  return a + 1;
}
```

Given these three files, we can create 'shared libraries' on which `main.cpp` depends:

```
$ g++ -shared x.cpp -o libx.so
$ g++ -shared y.cpp -o liby.so
```

Now, we can compile our main function by linking the respective libraries:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -L. -ly -lx
```

To execute the program, first we need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the compiler to find the newly created 'shared libraries':

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:.
$ ./a.out
```

And we can immediately check the result:

```
$ echo $? 
4
```

If we are on Ubuntu 16 or 17, the compile command is dependent on the order of its arguments. For example, this won’t link properly yielding an undefined reference:

```
$ g++ -L. -ly main.cpp -lx
/tmp/ccYWLawS.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `y_func(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Check out that this won’t link neither:

```
$ g++ -L. -ly -lx main.cpp
/tmp/ccEYEAtM.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `x_global'
main.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `y_func(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But if your are on Debian 7, 8, or 9 these two aforementioned examples will compile without a problem. Account that we've worked with shared (or dynamic) libraries (*.so) here. When we work with static libraries (*.a), the order does matter for both OSs.

I've written this post based on the reading recommendation from Mike Kinghan and [Beginner's Guide to Linkers](http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html#objpng) article.