# Using OPCUA Library in a New Cmake Project

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, opc-ua

In this time, I want to use [Freeopcua](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua) to create a library to use in other project.

I have install all the tools in `debian.soft` file and build with following command `sudo sh build.sh`, `cmake .`, `make`, `sudo make install`. Although, in directory `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`, there are `opc` directory and `libopc*.so` respectively, when I create a new cmake project, there is an error. Hope someone can help me or give some suggest. Thanks everyone~~~

I have refer to [Libraries in /usr/local/lib not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889799/libraries-in-usr-local-lib-not-found), but it doesn't work for me

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

project(OPCUAIndependent)

include_directories(/usr/local/include/)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib/)

add_executable(sourceCode sourceCode.cpp)

target_link_libraries(sourceCode opc)
```

Error

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable sourceCode
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/sourceCode.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'sourceCode' failed
make[2]: *** [sourceCode] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sourceCode.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sourceCode.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: In the `target_link_libraries` command you should specify **exact name** of the library you want to link. If you want to link with `opcuaprotocol` library, use `target_link_libraries(sourceCode opcuaprotocol)`, if you want to link with `opcuacore` library, use `target_link_libraries(sourceCode opcuacore)`, if you want to link with both of them, use `target_link_libraries(sourceCode opcuacore opcuaprotocol)`.

Comment: Thank you, the error disappear, but there still some error when I execute binary file. `malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion`

Comment: Therefore, I find when I use 
`if(NOT opcuaprotocol_FOUND) find_package(opcuaprotocol REQUIRED) endif()`
in CMakeList.txt, it say Could not find a package configuration file provided by "opcuaprotocol" with any of the following names
`opcuaprotocolConfig.cmake`
`opcuaprotocol-config.cmake`

Comment: According to the project's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L613), the name of the package to search is `FreeOpcUa`. E.g. `find_package(FreeOpcUa REQUIRED)`. This call creates targets like `opcuacore` or `opcuaprotocol`, so you could use them in the `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works for me. Finally, I just modify origin `CMakeLists.txt` including deleting `add_library`, and adding `find_package(FreeOpcUa REQUIRED)`...,etc, instead of creating a new ‵CMakeLists.txt‵.